# Game vectors are going askew

Tags: c++, vector, path

I have to create a prototype for a game I pitched, and the game is being made in the engine owned by the university and uses C++.

The problem I'm having is the bullet that is supposed to head from the character sprite towards an object that is tied to the cursor at time of firing, doesn't head true towards it unless the cursor is in the exact center of the screen.

Here is my code for these parts of the game:

```html
//all relevant variable declarations (these are outside the game loop)
float speed = 0.01;
float Mx = 0, My = 0, mouseX, mouseY;
int shoot = -1;
float bulletX, bulletY;
float distanceX, distanceY, length;
float directionX, directionY;

//Cursor movement
myEngine->StartMouseCapture();  // starting capture of mouse
mouseX = myEngine->GetMouseMovementX(); //moving x axis
mouseY = myEngine->GetMouseMovementY(); //moving y axis
cursor->MoveX(mouseX / 50);   // divide by 50 to slow down speed
cursor->MoveY((mouseY / 50)*-1); //-1 otherwise it's inverted
//End of cursor movement

if((myEngine->KeyHit( Key_Space ) || myEngine->KeyHeld( Key_Space ) ) && shoot == -1) //whilst space bar is pressed or held, and shoot is -1 meaning no bullet exists
 {
  //bullet creation and setup
  bullet = sphereMesh->CreateModel( sprite->GetX(), sprite->GetY(), sprite->GetZ() ); //spawning bullet on current location of character
  bullet->Scale(0.02); //shrinking model to appropriate size
  bullet->SetSkin( "EarthClouds.jpg" ); //changing appearance of model
  shoot = 2000; //starting the count down till bullet removal

  //bullet vector calculations
  bulletX = cursor->GetX() - sprite->GetX(); //x vector calculation
  bulletY = cursor->GetY() - sprite->GetY(); //y vector calculation

  distanceX = bulletX * bulletX; //
  distanceY = bulletY * bulletY; //
  length = sqrt( distanceX + distanceY ); //calculating distance between models

  directionX = bulletX / length; //calculating x direction
  directionY = bulletY / length; // calculating y direction
  //end of bullet vector calculations
 }

if(shoot>0)
 {
  bullet->MoveX( directionX / 50 ); //move x by calculated direction above divide by 50 to slow down
  bullet->MoveY( directionY / 50 ); //move y by calculated direction above divide by 50 to slow down
  shoot--; //reducing shoot counter
 }
else if(shoot == 0)
 {
  sphereMesh->RemoveModel(bullet); //removes bullet model
  shoot--; //reduces shoot counter to -1 to allow spawn of another bullet
 }
```

Comment: Nevermind I solved it, my z axis between the two models didn't match up

Answer (score 0):

Model Z axis' didn't match up, creating problems for the 3D engine